# Unable to update location info into textfield

Tags: swift, core-location

I am creating a reverse geocoder and faced problems trying to run it. It only shows the address of the previous location.

When I run my code, it doesn't show any text in the text field. When I try to change my location in the simulator, the text field shows the address of the previous location. Please advise on how to fix this problem.

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController , CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate{
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var locationTextField: UITextField!

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    var geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    var currentLocation : CLLocation?
    var currentLocationPlacemark : [CLPlacemark]?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = true
            locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        }

        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        mapView.isZoomEnabled = true

        let initialLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 21.282778, longitude: -157.829444)

        currentLocation = initialLocation

        centerMapOnLocation(location: initialLocation)

        reverseGeocode()

        print("initial location called.")
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        currentLocation = locations.last!

        centerMapOnLocation(location: currentLocation!)

        reverseGeocode()

        print("did update location")

//        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

    let regionRadius: CLLocationDistance = 500

    func centerMapOnLocation(location: CLLocation) {
        let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location.coordinate,
                                                  latitudinalMeters: regionRadius, longitudinalMeters: regionRadius)
        mapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
    }

    func reverseGeocode(){
        if let location = currentLocation {
            geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { (placemark, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    self.locationTextField.text = "Error getting location"
                    print("error getting location")
                }
                else {
                    self.currentLocationPlacemark = placemark
                    print(self.currentLocationPlacemark)
                }
            }
            print("Successfully got location")
        }

        if let placemark = currentLocationPlacemark?.last{
            if let name = placemark.name {
                var result = name

                if let street = placemark.thoroughfare {
                    result += ", \(street)"
                }

                if let city = placemark.locality {
                    result += ", \(city)"
                }

                locationTextField.text = result

                print("Successfully got address")
            }
            print("Location placemark Received.")
        }
        print("Reverse Geocode Method called.")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your function reverseGeocode() doesn't work, like you intended. It is also overly complicated and I'm not sure why you made the function this way. 
You created that property currentLocationPlacemark that you then try to fill with the place mark retrieved from the reverse geocoding. I think this is not really necessary. The created property currentLocationPlacemark is empty and the code after `if let place mark = currentLocationPlacemark?.last` is not being called, since currentLocationPlacemark is empty.

Please, try to write your function reverseGeocode() like the code below and you'll see the textfield is being updated.

```
func reverseGeocode(){

    var result = ""

    if let location = currentLocation {
        geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { (placemark, error) in

            guard error == nil else {
                self.locationTextField.text = "Error getting location"
                print("error getting location")
                return
            }

            if let name = placemark?.first?.name {
                result = name
            }
            if let street = placemark?.first?.thoroughfare {
                result += " \(street)"
            }
            if let city = placemark?.first?.locality {
                result += " \(city)"
            }

            self.locationTextField.text = result

            print("Successfully got location")
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, why do you use a textfield and not a label?

Comment: Hi, thank you so much. I am a beginner in programming and thank you so much for your advice and it really helps. Oh and i use a textfield because it is user editable when they click on it. Thanks.